# Find coefficients to a quadratic equation knowing roots and a point...

Tags: quadratics

Given a standard quadratic equation:
$$p(z) = az^2 + bz + c$$

We know that $-10$ and $10-i$ are roots.
We know that $p(i)=-10$

What are $a$, $b$ and $c$?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried to write $p(z)$ as a factored quadratic based off the given information?

Comment: Yes. It gives (z+10)(z-10+i) = z^2+zi-100+10i. While this polynomial has roots -10 and 10-i, it does not satisfy p(i)=-10. I don't know how to include that last piece of information.

Comment: Ah, remember that knowing that the roots of a quadratic are $r,s$ only tells you that $p(x)=C(x-r)(x-s)$.  No matter what constant you put for $C$, the roots are unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$p(z)=C(z+10)(z-10+i)\\p(z)=C(z^2-10z+zi+10z-100+10i)\\p(z) = C(z^2+zi+10i-100)$$
The condition is that 
$$p(i) = -10$$
This means that
$$ C(i^2+i\cdot i+10i-100) =-10$$
$$C(-102+10i) =-10\\C=\frac{10}{102-10i}=\frac{5}{51-5i}$$
$$C=\frac{5}{51-5i}\cdot\frac{51+5i}{51+5i}$$
$$C = \frac{255+25i}{2626}$$
Now plug in $C$, and we can get
$$p(z) = \frac{255+25i}{2626}(z^2+zi+10i-100)$$
$$p(z) = \frac{255+25i}{2626}z^2+\frac{255+25i}{2626}zi+(10i-100)\cdot \frac{255+25i}{2626}$$
$$p(z) = \frac{255+25i}{2626}z^2+\frac{-25+255i}{2626}z+(5i-50)\cdot \frac{255+25i}{1313}$$

$$p(z) = \frac{255+25i}{2626}z^2+\frac{-25+255i}{2626}z+\frac{-12875+25i}{1313}$$
**Result:**
$$a = \frac{255+25i}{2626},b=\frac{-25+255i}{2626},c=\frac{-12875+25i}{1313}$$

Comment: Got it! Thanks. I got the same result before seeing your calculation, however it took me an hour :-D

Answer (score 1):

Try $p(z)=a(z-i)(z-10+i)$

Multiply and find coefficients using the information at $z=i$